# Azure Pipelines CI not triggering when pushing tags from Bitbucket

Tags: git, continuous-integration, azure-devops, bitbucket, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to do a proof of concept to redesign my CI/CD pipelines in Azure Pipelines (formerly known as VSTS). My codebase is in BitBucket.

I need a continuous integration build to be triggered when I push git tags to the remote repo.[image]

The proof of concept works really well when I use Azure Repos (VSTS), it detects a change in the "branch" "refs/tags/current" and triggers the build.

[image]

But once I switch to BitBucket, it just doesn't work, no build is triggered.

So my question is:

**How can I trigger a CI build in Azure Pipelines (VSTS) when pushing tags to my BitBucket repo?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, we cannot achieve that for the service connection endpoints (`BitBucket` here) , CI only works when you push commits with **new changes** (The real file/code changes).

But push git tags only added tags to a commit, no any other new file changes be pushed to the remote repo.

So, if you want to trigger the CI build by pushing tags only, then it will not work...

I can think of is that you can add a insignificant file in source control (a `*.txt` file for example). Then edit/modify the file every time when you push tags. After finishing push tags, you need to push the new changes for the `*.txt` file, but it will generate a new commit...not the commit you added tags for it...

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for the answer. Do you mean it doesn't work with Bitbucket only? Because with Azure Repos works like a charm. Another option would be adding a commit WITH a tag, and then push the commit along with the tag, but I need a way to detect the tag in the pipeline. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @GustavoVargas Yes, I mean the service connection endpoints (`BitBucket` here), as far as I know no any way to achieve that.

Comment: Ok thanks Andy. Then I will think in another way to orchestrate the pipelines.

Comment: @GustavoVargas You can migrate from BitBucket to VSTS internal Git, or try syncing between BitBucket and VSTS internal Git. This blog for your reference : https://blogs.microsoft.co.il/leonj/2017/01/24/synchronizing-tfs-2015-and-vsts-with-github/#GITHUB_TFS

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by doing the following steps (This is using Github, though).

### Go to the triggers for your pipeline in Azure DevOps:

[image]

Enter two branch specifications:

```
- refs/tags/*
- releases/*
```

*PS: These needs to match whereever your repo hosting provider archives releases and tags.*

Click **Save** (not Save & Queue)

---

### Create a new tag on Github

[image]

Click the "Draft new release"

[image]

Enter the details for your release.

#### Pipeline picked up the new tag, and builds it

[image]

Comment: Hi Coreus, thank you for sharing this. Not sure if you tested on BitBucket. I tried the same setup with BitBucket, but VSTS is not triggered.