# Triggering a Release pipeline when adding git tag in Github

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to automatically trigger a Azure Release pipeline upon adding a git tag in Github.

I tried to specify as branch on the Continuous Deployment trigger for the Artifact:

- `/refs/tags/*`
- `*`

but both options do not trigger a release upon creation of a git tag.

When I use `*` as trigger filter and push a commit to e.g. the `master` branch of my repo I am able to trigger the Release pipeline.

Am I missing something here, or is it a Azure DevOps limitation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52373011/azure-pipelines-ci-not-triggering-when-pushing-tags-from-bitbucket

Comment: Not a duplicate, difference is that this is about the release pipeline and not build pipeline as the other adresses

Comment: A fix for pushing new branches has rolled out last week to all of Azure Repo's. This may have also fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to use the [Azure/pipelines](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/azure-pipelines-action) GitHub Action to trigger the Azure Pipeline.

The actions to support this were announced in the [Azure DevOps Sprint 161 release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-161-update#use-github-actions-to-trigger-a-run-in-azure-pipelines)

An [example is available on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/actions-workflow-samples/blob/master/AzurePipelines/trigger-azure-pipelines.yml), the interesting bit is this:

```yaml
 deploy-using-azure-pipelines:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: 'Trigger an Azure Pipeline to deploy the app to PRODUCTION'
      uses: Azure/pipelines@releases/v1
      with:
        azure-devops-project-url: 'https://dev.azure.com/OrganizationName/ProjectName'
        azure-pipeline-name: 'WebApp_Azure_Prod' 
        azure-devops-token: '${{ secrets.AZURE_DEVOPS_TOKEN }}'
```

You would need to change the URL and create a secret named `AZURE_DEVOPS_TOKEN` in the GitHub project that has an Azure DevOps personal access token.

The trigger for your GitHub Action workflow could use something similar to the answers in [Trigger Github Action only on new tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61891328/trigger-github-action-only-on-new-tags)