# Trigger Github Action only on new tags?

Tags: github, github-actions

Is there a possibility to trigger a GitHub action only if a new version (which comes with a new tag) is pushed? I don't want run them on every push into master, but I also want to avoid creating a release branch.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Use the following syntax:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    # Pattern matched against refs/tags
    tags:        
      - '*'           # Push events to every tag not containing /
```

For hierarchical tags:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    # Pattern matched against refs/tags
    tags:        
      - '**'           # Push events to every tag including hierarchical tags like v1.0/beta
```

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#patterns-to-match-branches-and-tags

Comment: Might you be able to add a full (basic) working example .yml? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "full (basic) working example"? The original question doesn't ask for anything like that.

Comment: What about an individual job (if statement)? This example only shows how you do it for the whole workflow file.

Comment: any ideas that trigger when new tags, but on master branch only?

Comment: Any idea how to access the created tag inside the workflow? like ${{ github.something }}

Comment: @jplus2 you probably want to have a look at GitHub Actions Contexts: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts

Answer (score 42):

The goal is to trigger a workflow when a tag is pushed, e.g. doing something like:

```
git tag v1.0.0
git push origin v1.0.0
```

In the workflow file:
e.g. `ci.yml`

```yaml
name: CI
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+'
```

This will run if someone pushes a semantic versioned tag to the GitHub repo.

One mistake I made was when migrating from Travis CI to GitHub Actions is that I **incorrectly** used

> `'^v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'`

as the pattern, which is **WRONG**. So check your pattern syntax if the workflow is not being triggered.

Comment: The pattern didn't consider alpha, beta, etc. versions, which might be an issue for advanced projects.

Comment: Hi @Szabolcs, I think you are right that this only addresses the major.minor.patch part of semantic versioning. A similar example is being used in the GitHub workflow docs [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#patterns-to-match-branches-and-tags). If you have the full & robust pattern to capture the versioning, please feel free to edit the post! Thanks.

Comment: Try this: `v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*([-\.]\S+)?`. It matches tags like `v1`, `v1.2`, and `v1.2.3-alpha.1` and `v1.2.3.alpha.1-build.123+sha.456`.

Comment: `'v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*([-\.]\S+)?'` yields `push event contained invalid tags patterns: v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*([-\.]\S+)?`

Comment: The value is not a regular expression, it's a [glob pattern](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet). You _can_ list multiple patterns, though, so you could do something like `["v[0-9]+", "v[0-9]+.[0-9]+", "v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+", "v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+-*"]`

Answer (score 26):

I got it to work with

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*'
```

I found out that if the tag was previously created (locally) *before* the workflow was created, no matter how many times I deleted and re-pushed the tag, it would not trigger until I deleted the tag locally and recreated it. The action does not seem to work for tags created before the workflow.

Comment: This drove me crazy for an hour, was trying to trigger based on a new tag.

Doesn't work:

`git push origin :1.2.3.0 ; git push origin --tags`

Works:

`git tag -d 1.2.3.0 ; git tag 1.2.3.0 ; git push origin :1.2.3.0 ; git push origin --tags`