# Run a github action after new tag creation

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, workflow, github-actions

```
 on:
     push:
       tags:
        - '*' # Push events to every tag
```

which I got from [Trigger Github Action only on new tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61891328/trigger-github-action-only-on-new-tags)

I created this github action, thinking that it would run after a newly created tag.

So I pushed this on a branch, as `.github/workflows/onnewtag.yml` file.

Then, staying on this same branch, I created a new tag:
`git tag -a 0.0.1 -m "first attempt"`.

Then I pushed this new tag:
`git push <remote> <branch> --tags`

But nothing happens.
Obviously there must be some thinking mistake on my side?

I have also tried pushing to the tag itself:

`git checkout tags/0.0.1 -b tags-test`
then edit something, `git add` and `git commit`, then
`git push <remote> <tag>`
For this I even get "Everything up-to-date"

What we really want is an action which will run every time we create a new release.
We were thinking that creating a tag would signal a new release.
Maybe tags is the wrong way to do this?

Comment: If you want a workflow to run when you create a new release then you can use the [`on: release`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#release) event.

Comment: I am sorry. This actually works. I was just using tags wrongly. If I do `git push <remote> <tag>` it works if I first create a tag: `git tag -a <tag>-m "text"`

Answer (score 4):

The [release](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#release) event is useful here.

Since you want the event to run each time a new release is published, you can use the `published` activity type to filter out editing/deleting/etc...

```yaml
on:
  release:
    types: [published]
```

You may also wish to consider adding the `prereleased` tag depending on your specific use case.

Comment: Yep. Nice. Thanks. But actually, my own code above works with tags, as I explained in the comment. If I do it properly :)

Comment: How can you reference the tag name in the release event?