# trigger github action only when new tags on master branch

Tags: github, github-actions

In this question [Trigger Github Action only on new tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61891328/trigger-github-action-only-on-new-tags)

I can trigger the build on new tag.

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+'
```

But if I'd like to add another condition, that only the tag on master branch. what should I do?

Or do I have to add if condition in jobs?

```
ame: CI
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+'

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: test
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
    steps:
```

Comment: A tag is not created "on" a branch. A tag is just something that points to something. Therefore, what you probably could do is listen for created tags and then check if the current sha ($GITHUB_REF) points to the top of master.