# GitHub Workflows: How do I additionally tag a Docker image when building only on master?

Tags: github-actions

I've been digging around for a while and can't quite figure out how to accomplish this.

**What I have now:** End-to-end, I have two workflows.  One monitors for new releases of Pi-hole and the other builds a docker image when new commits happen.

**Goal:** Using GitHub Workflows, only when committing to the `master` branch, I want to build a single Docker image that is tagged with `master`, `latest`, and every tag on the commit (usually a version tag), if they exist.  This way, whether I do a commit to `master` or my Pi-hole monitor workflow does a commit, the appropriate docker image tags will be published from only a single build run.

**Use case 1:** I commit an update to `master` with a change to Dockerfile.  The result should be that a new docker image is published with both `master` and `latest` tags.  A single docker image should be used so the SHAs for the tags match.  The current Pi-hole version-tagged image should remain untouched.

This currently works!  I get one docker build run which publishes the image under `master` and `latest`.

**Use case 2:** My Pi-hole monitor workflow detects a new Pi-hole release.  The result should be that a new docker image is published with three tags: `master`, `latest`, and the Pi-hole release tag (e.g. `pihole-v5.10`).  A single docker image should be used so the SHAs for the tags match.

This does not currently work. This triggers my workflow twice.  So, two docker builds run.  `latest` is updated twice (whichever finishes first).  The `master` and version tags (`pihole-v*.*`) have different SHAs.

**Workflow #1: Pi-hole monitor**

```yaml
name: Pi-hole Monitor
on:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '0 8 * * *'
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  check-pihole-version:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # https://github.com/actions/checkout
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67550727/push-event-doesnt-trigger-workflow-on-push-paths-github-actions
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.BUILD_AUTOMATION_TOKEN }}

      - name: Fetch latest release version of Pi-hole
        id: pi-hole_ver
        run: |
          curl -sL https://api.github.com/repos/pi-hole/pi-hole/releases/latest | \
          jq -r ".tag_name" > pihole-latest.txt
          echo ::set-output name=pihole-latest::$(cat pihole-latest.txt)

      - name: Check for modified files
        id: git-check
        run: echo ::set-output name=modified::$([ -z "`git status --porcelain`" ] && echo "false" || echo "true")

      - name: Commit latest release version
        if: steps.git-check.outputs.modified == 'true'
        run: |
          git config --global user.name 'Hossy'
          git config --global user.email 'Hossy@users.noreply.github.com'
          git commit -am "New Pi-hole release ${{ steps.pi-hole_ver.outputs.pihole-latest }}"
          git tag -am "Pi-hole ${{ steps.pi-hole_ver.outputs.pihole-latest }}" pihole-${{ steps.pi-hole_ver.outputs.pihole-latest }}
          git push origin pihole-${{ steps.pi-hole_ver.outputs.pihole-latest }}
          git push
```

**Workflow #2: Docker builder**

```yaml
name: Publish Docker Image

# This workflow uses actions that are not certified by GitHub.
# They are provided by a third-party and are governed by
# separate terms of service, privacy policy, and support
# documentation.

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '37 8 1,15 * *'
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
    tags: [ 'pihole-**' ]
    paths-ignore: [ '.github/**' ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  # Use docker.io for Docker Hub if empty
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  # github.repository as <account>/<repo>
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      packages: write

    steps:
      # Login against a Docker registry except on PR
      # https://github.com/docker/login-action
      - name: Log into registry ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: docker/login-action@v2.0.0
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      # Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
      # https://github.com/docker/metadata-action
      - name: Extract Docker metadata
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4.0.1
        with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}
          # set latest tag for master branch
          tags: |
            type=schedule
            type=ref,event=branch
            type=ref,event=tag
            type=ref,event=pr
            type=raw,value=latest,enable={{is_default_branch}}

      # Build and push Docker image with Buildx (don't push on PR)
      # https://github.com/docker/build-push-action
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3.0.0
        with:
          push: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```

Other things that might help that I've looked at and are still tinkering with:

- [trigger github action only when new tags on master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71535871/trigger-github-action-only-when-new-tags-on-master-branch)
- [Add a tag to a Docker image if there's a git tag using GitHub Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66017161/add-a-tag-to-a-docker-image-if-theres-a-git-tag-using-github-action)

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question, I continued to dig and I found a solution.  I'm not going to claim it's a pretty solution, but it accomplishes the goal.

I'd also like to add that, at the very most, the GitHub API is severely lacking.  But I digress... to the good stuff!

What I ended up doing is:

1. Using a [GitHub API call](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#list-repository-tags) to `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/tags`, retrieve every tag that exists on the repository.  This is the only API call I found that would return the commit SHA of the tag.  All the others kept returning the object SHA of the tag itself (useless to me).

Example output (JSON array):

```json
[
    {
        "name": "pihole-v5.10",
        "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Hossy/pihole/zipball/refs/tags/pihole-v5.10",
        "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Hossy/pihole/tarball/refs/tags/pihole-v5.10",
        "commit": {
            "sha": "e696d33d0dca3df5157cbc8558cc303cec027851",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Hossy/pihole/commits/e696d33d0dca3df5157cbc8558cc303cec027851"
        },
        "node_id": "MDM6UmVmMjc4NDM1ODg3OnJlZnMvdGFncy9waWhvbGUtdjUuMTA="
    }
]
```

2. Parse the JSON output with `jq` and filter to the tag that has a commit SHA that matches the workflow's commit SHA.
3. Do some string manipulation to merge the tags from `docker/metadata-action` and GitHub API (`jq`) to build a superset of tags for `docker/build-push-action`.

My new docker builder workflow:

```yaml
name: Publish Docker Image

# This workflow uses actions that are not certified by GitHub.
# They are provided by a third-party and are governed by
# separate terms of service, privacy policy, and support
# documentation.

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '37 8 1,15 * *'
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
    #tags: [ 'pihole-**' ]
    paths-ignore: [ '.github/**' ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
  # workflow_dispatch:

env:
  # Use docker.io for Docker Hub if empty
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  # github.repository as <account>/<repo>
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      # contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:
      # Login against a Docker registry except on PR
      # https://github.com/docker/login-action
      - name: Log into registry ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: docker/login-action@v2.0.0
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      # Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
      # https://github.com/docker/metadata-action
      - name: Extract Docker metadata
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4.0.1
        with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}
          # set latest tag for master branch
          tags: |
            type=schedule
            type=ref,event=branch
            type=ref,event=tag
            type=ref,event=pr
            type=raw,value=latest,enable={{is_default_branch}}

      # Retrieve all repository tags from the GitHub API using undocumented API call to get all tags
      # https://github.com/actions/github-script
      - name: Get all tags
        id: all-tags
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            const path = "/repos/" + "${{ github.repository }}" + "/tags"
            const parameters = "{'" + "${{ github.repository_owner }}" + "', '" + "${{ github.repository }}" + "'}"
            return github.rest.git.getTag(path,parameters)
      
      # Prepare JSON output for Unix command line
      # https://github.com/mad9000/actions-find-and-replace-string
      - name: Format jq result
        id: formatted-jq
        uses: mad9000/actions-find-and-replace-string@2
        with:
          source: ${{ steps.all-tags.outputs.result }}
          find: "'"
          replace: "\\\'"

      # Parse Github API output and search for tags only matching the current commit SHA 
      - name: Search all tags for commit
        id: tag-results
        run: echo ::set-output name=tags::"$( echo '${{ steps.formatted-jq.outputs.value }}' | jq -r ".data | .[] | select( .commit.sha == \"${{ github.sha }}\" ) | .name" )"
      
      # Merge the tag lists from docker/metadata-action and GitHub API
      - name: Build tag list
        id: tag-list
        run: |
          echo ::set-output name=tags::"$(
            echo -n "${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}" | tr '\n' ','
            for r in `echo "${{ steps.tag-results.outputs.tags }}" | tr '\n' ' '`; do echo -n ,${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}:$r | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'; done
          )"

      # Build and push Docker image with Buildx (don't push on PR)
      # https://github.com/docker/build-push-action
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3.0.0
        with:
          # context: .
          push: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
          tags: ${{ steps.tag-list.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```