# Is it possible to Trigger builds on App Center based on GitHub commit IDs? or Git tags?

Tags: react-native, github, visual-studio-app-center, appcenter

Currently we can trigger builds on every new push on a particular branch which has been configured. But what if I want to trigger a build for a specific commit?
example. I have commits A, B, C, D and now I have to trigger a build specifically for commit B.

I tried to find references for the same but did not find any.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger Github Action only on new tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61891328/trigger-github-action-only-on-new-tags)

Comment: @user18309290 No, The answer states how It can be achieved using GitHub Actions. I am looking if it is possible using App Center.